# How to load game quickly in Star Trek 25th Annivrsary?

Tags: dosbox, star-trek-25th-anniversary

I'm replaying *Star Trek: 25th Anniversary* (the first adventure game I ever played). It runs fine in DosBox.

One small problem: whenever I play to resume my game I have to run `startrek.exe` then wait / skip through the game and first mission introductions before I can choose the 'load' command.

Is there a quicker way?